# Android Asynctask won't finish

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-asynctask, adt

I'm writing a really simple game for school, but the use of asynctask is required. I'm using ADT (Eclipse). Here is the relevant code:

```
 public void oklog(View view) throws ParserConfigurationException, TransformerConfigurationException, TransformerException, URISyntaxException, ClientProtocolException, IOException, IllegalStateException, SAXException {

    new log_async().execute();
}

String DocumentToString(Document doc) throws TransformerConfigurationException, TransformerException{
    TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(writer));
    String output = writer.getBuffer().toString();//.replaceAll("\n|\r", "");

    return output;
}
class log_async extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    protected void onPreExecute(){

        TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        tv1.setText("Pracuję...");

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String...voids ) {

        TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        tv1.setText("haha");
        String a = "";
        try {
            tv1.setText("haha2");

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = null;
        docBuilder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        tv1.setText("haha3");
        Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();

        Element env = doc.createElementNS("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", "soap:Envelope");
        Element body = doc.createElementNS("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", "soap:Body");
        Element zaloguj = doc.createElementNS("http://tempuri.org/", "tc:Zaloguj");
        zaloguj.appendChild(doc.createElementNS("http://tempuri.org/", "tc:login"));
        zaloguj.appendChild(doc.createElementNS("http://tempuri.org/", "tc:pass"));

        EditText et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        zaloguj.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://tempuri.org/", "login").item(0).setTextContent(et1.getText().toString());
        EditText et2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        zaloguj.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://tempuri.org/", "pass").item(0).setTextContent(et2.getText().toString());

        tv1.setText("haha4");
        body.appendChild(zaloguj);
        env.appendChild(body);
        doc.appendChild(env);

        String s = null;
        s = DocumentToString(doc);

        Log.i("SOAP", s);

        StringEntity entity = null;

        entity = new StringEntity(s);
        HttpPost post = null;
        post = new HttpPost(new URI("http://www.kdkade.somee.com/oldschoolrpg_main.asmx"));
        tv1.setText("haha5");
        post.addHeader("SOAPAction", "http://tempuri.org/Zaloguj");
        post.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");

        post.setEntity(entity);
        HttpResponse response = null;
        response = client.execute(post);
        Document responseDoc = null;

        responseDoc = docBuilder.parse(response.getEntity().getContent());

        tv1.setText("haha6");
        s = DocumentToString(responseDoc);

        Log.i("RESPONSE", s);

        //TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        String[] temp1 = s.split("<ZalogujResult>");
        String[] temp2 = temp1[1].split("</");
        tv1.setText(temp2[0]);
        a = temp2[0];
        //tv1.setText(responseDoc.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://tempuri.org/","ZalogujResult").toString());
        //tv1.setText(s);
        //return null;
        //return null;
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            tv1.setText(e.getMessage());
        }
        tv1.setText("wtf");
        return a;
    }

    //protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        //setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
    //}

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        tv1.setText(result);
    }
```

The code inside doinbackground was in oklog method before and it worked fine. As you can see, I put some TextView textchanges here and there, to see on the emulator how far is it going and it's sometimes only "Pracuję..." (the one in OnPreExecute) , sometimes it goes even to "haha5" and sometimes app crashes (seems fairly random). Unfortunately, I'm lost what's wrong here. Can anyone tell me where is the mistake or is it emulator problem?

Comment: you are trying to update ui in doInbackground. tv1.setText("haha2");. you should use runonuithread to do the same or in onPostExecute(param)

Comment: As I said after pasting the code, this is only temporary as it didn't work without the haha# textchanges. It was just always "Pracuję" from OnPreExecute.

Comment: that's because onPreExecute() invoked on the ui thread so it gets displayed. check the logcat and the line of the crash. check the link for more info http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to update UI on the background thread. You should update ui on the main ui thread. `doInbackground()` is invoked on the background thread immediately after `onPreExecute()` finishes executing. This step is used to perform background computation that can take a long time. Use `runOnUiThread()` to update UI in `doInBackground()`.

`onProgressUpdate(Progress...)` is invoked on the UI thread. It can be used to animate a progress bar or show logs in a text field. You can use this also.

But i would suggest you update UI in `onPostExecute(param)`. The result of `doInBackground()` is a param to `onPostExecute(param)`. `onPostExecute(param)` is invoked on the UI thread.

Also you can initialize your textview once in `onCreate()` and use the same.

You can check the topic under The 4 steps @ http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

@Override
public void run(){

// update ui here

}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the answer above, you are updating UI from a non-UI thread (i.e, the background thread that the `log_async` is running on).

An option for communicating progress within the `doInBackground()` method, is to use `publishProgress()`, which will in turn which cause the `onProgressUpdate()` to be called subsequently.

You would also need to override `onProgressUpdate()` to update the UI appropriately.